# C# Not Disposing controls like I told it to

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, dispose

I have a Panel control. And inside the panel users can add combobox's, textbox's labels etc and drag them around and stuff, and there's a Delete button on my form where if they click it, it will delete all controls inside that panel. BUT this code:

```
foreach( Control control in panel.Controls )
{
     control.Dispose();
}
```

... Does not work properly. It doesn't always Dispose of ALL the controls inside the panel. Sometimes it gets rid of most of them, sometimes it only gets rid of one or two. Sometimes all but 1 are Disposed. WTF?

**EDIT:**

---

Here is the code I use to add the controls to the Panel:

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
    tbox.Multiline = true;
    tbox.IsAccessible = true;

    panel.Controls.Add(tbox);
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I'll edit my question with the code used to create the controls.

Comment: I agree with Dan Herbert's answer. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what calling dispose does.

Comment: I thought you meant "WPF" instead of "WTF", but I guess you had it right the first time. :)

Comment: Calling `Dispose` doesn't actually necessarily do anything, and it certainly doesn't necessarily cause the control to close or disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simpler way to delete all your controls is to do this:

```
panel.Controls.Clear();
```

**Edit:** thanks to Pieter and Paolo, just calling Clear() like this will leak memory since the controls are not disposed, so this is not a good practice.

Comment: Note that this won't dispose your controls. It only removes them from the collection.

Comment: @Pieter: note also that not every control needs to have Dispose() called on it, which I guess is what you're saying. Otherwise, removing them from the controls collection *will* expose them to garbage collection, assuming they're not also referenced elsewhere. It appears that OP only used Dispose() originally based on a misunderstanding of how to "delete" controls.

Comment: @MusiGenesis [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx) explicity says: Calling the `Clear` method does not remove control handles from memory. **You must explicitly call the `Dispose` method to avoid memory leaks**.

Answer (score 8):

`Dispose()` only cleans up unmanaged resources (although Paul Williams noted in the comments that it is usually more complex than this!) so it may or may not do anything useful in your case.

Try removing the controls with the `RemoveAt(i)` method, not `Dispose()`:

```
for(int i = panel.Controls.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    panel.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Or you can use panel.Controls.Clear() if you want to remove them all. Control.ControlCollection will take care of clean up if necessary.

Comment: A proper overridden Dispose(boolean) method disposes of both managed and unmanaged resouces.  Dispose(true) means dispose of both.  Dispose(false) means you have a finalizer, and the finalizer called the Dispose method.  If called from a finalizer, the Dispose method must not touch any other managed objects.  It's too late for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this before, you are removing items from acollection that make the collection itself smaller.
e.g if there are 5 items in the collection as you move down through it you come to the end of the list sooner than you expect because the list gets smaller with every Dispose() you issue.

Comment: Not sure that's going to apply in a foreach loop.

Comment: thank you Darrin that was much appreciated. I understand what's going on now. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know is a pretty old post, but I hope could help somebody.

The only way I found that works is:

```
while(panel.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    panel.Controls[0].Dispose();
}
```

This way it doesn't matter if the list of Controls become smaller in the middle of the loop.