# Deleting all controls on a Winform with a foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, dispose

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Not Disposing controls like I told it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493309/c-sharp-not-disposing-controls-like-i-told-it-to)

I use this to delete all Pictureboxes I created on my Winform

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls)
{
    pb.Dispose();
}
```

but each time only about the half of all Pictureboxes get disposed, 
the other half remains untouched

i solved it by surrounding it with a `while (Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Count() > 0 )` Loop
so it just gets executed until all Pictureboxes are gone,
but this is a bad solution and i want to know why this happens and how i can solve it the right way

Comment: Do you have a control on the form which is not a picture box?

Comment: Yes, so just disposing all controls is not an option

Comment: Might be worth removing your controls from the form's Controls collection before disposing them! Also as you have controls other than `PictureBox`es, you should change your loop: `foreach (Control c in this.Controls) { if (!(c is PictureBox)) continue; c.Dispose(); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Control.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w) is removing the control from the collection, changing the index and messing up the foreach.

You can solve this problem by using a reverse for loop or by creating a separate array holding the references.

**Solution #0**

```
for (int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Controls[i].Dispose();
}
```

**Solution #1**

```
foreach (var control in Controls.Cast<Control>().ToArray())
{
    control.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: that's the Answer i was searching for - Thank you

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue with this `foreach (TextBox t in panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())` and adding the `.ToArray()` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try With:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if(c is PictureBox) 
  {
   c.Dispose();
   this.Controls.Remove(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: same result...
I think the disposing somehow changes the index the foreach loop is using and so with every dispose one Control gets skipped

Comment: no, the problem is that it skips every second Picturebox when you loop directly through this.Control and dispose it there

Answer (score 0):

Because you have controls that are not a `PictureBox`, you loop will throw exception when it gets to this control. Fix your loop like that:

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray())
{
    pb.Dispose();
    this.Controls.Remove(pb);
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly
all picboxes are disposed at once as they should

Comment: The real problem is that when you call dispose on PB, it internally removes itself from its parent's controls list which is the very list you were iterating upon. This results in skipping of some PBs. In this solution you are essentially iterating upon a copy list and removing elements from the original list. For most controls calling dispose is enough and controls.remove is not necessary.